# Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I made e2e test for App component using Enzyme but this test falls with next error message:

> Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called
>   zero times.

What is causing the problem? Thank you in advance for help.

**Code with test error:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/x348jx4qzw

Test code:

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import App from "./app.js";
const movieTitlesCollection = [`Fantastic Beasts`];

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe(`AppComponent`, () => {
  it(`should simulate card title click`, () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <App movieTitles={movieTitlesCollection} onClick={handleClick} />
    );
    const filmCardTitle = wrapper.find(`.small-movie-card__link`);

    expect(filmCardTitle.length).toEqual(1);
    filmCardTitle.simulate(`click`);
    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please publish your code directly to your question.

Comment: I wonder `filmCardTitle` is called, but not `App`, unless you code call App's prop `onClick` when you click `filmCardTitle`. You probably should test your `FirmCardTitle` component, then you might have that `onClick` defined there.

Comment: @windmaomao, yeah thats right, thank you

Answer (score 0):

onClick property should be provided to 'small-movie-card__title in App component;

```
const App = ({movieTitles, onClick}) => {
      const filmCard = movieTitles.map((movieTitle, index) =>
        <article className="small-movie-card catalog__movies-card" key={index}>
          <button className="small-movie-card__play-btn" type="button">Play</button>
          <div className="small-movie-card__image">
            <img src="img/fantastic-beasts-the-crimes-of-grindelwald.jpg" alt="Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald" width="280" height="175"/>
          </div>
          <h3 className="small-movie-card__title">
            <a className="small-movie-card__link" href="movie-page.html" onClick={onClick}>
              { movieTitle }
            </a>
          </h3>
        </article>
      );

other code...
```